# Databricks - Wat are potential causes of different counts on different clusters

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I run exactly the same code in two notebooks.

One is attached to cluster X.
The second is attached to cluster Y. I count a total number of rows in a standard way:

```
print("Total rows", df.count())
```

In one notebook on cluster X I receive: 8696693.
In the 2nd notebook on cluster Y I receive: 8438583

What are the potential causes of this?

How to debug it?
I didn't setup / configured clusters.

**Update - what I've already done:**

1. I tested it even from the same notebook (got the same issue).
2. Tested it on a different (3rd) cluster, where values were the same (8696693) like X cluster but not like Y.
3. Compared the content of each cell (exactly the same).
4. Checked does a df for which I count no. of rows is kept in cash - no it's not.
5. Tested it from a new notebook. The same issue.

Any other ideas?

Comment: This could have a lot of different reasons. Your table could be receiving new data, caching, etc. It would be great if you could provide some more information.

Comment: @RobertKossendey non of those reasons. Because values for both are static each time I check it (always the same). So it's not due to changes in the source data. Yes, there's one caching in the whole flow but I cleaned it before getting a count to check is it the cause and apparently it was not.

Comment: Probably your code is not deterministic, so it will give different results, can you share your code ?

Comment: You probably do some transformation before the action (df.count()). If you are using non-deterministic functions in the transformations such as collect_list, first, last or external functions which depend on external factors, can cause different results in a different cluster.

Comment: Yes, that was (partially) the cause. The script was initiating a DF from some tables. And as it turned out clusters differed with accesses to some of the tables that were used. That was completely not obvious for me to check.